# Java: Recursive generics compiler error

Tags: java, generics

Given the following contrived example:

```
public class Child extends Parent<Child, String> () {}

public class Parent<E extends Parent, V> {

    public V value;

    // maps <List of Entities> to <List of Values>
    public List<V> filterValues(List<E> entities) {
        List<V> values = new ArrayList();
        for (E entity : entities) {
            values.add(entity.value); // compiler error: add(V) cannot be
                                      // applied to (java.lang.Object)
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```

I don't fully understand the nature of this error.  Is `List<V>` resolving to `List<Object>`?  How can I solve my problem of mapping a specific type to its associated field?

Comment: java, sorry should have mentioned

Comment: I mean which version ?

Comment: Replacing `E extends Parent` with `E extends Parent<E,V>` or `E extends Parent<?,V>` gave me no compiler errors (only a warning about unchecked operations). Perhaps try that?

Comment: Consider what happens if I were to define `public class Child2 extends Parent<Child, Integer> {}`, then call `new Child2().filterValues(Arrays.asList(new Child()))`. Your code would end up adding a `String` to a `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, it seems that you want to declare `Parent` as `class Parent<E extends Parent<?,V>, V>`.

It will compile, but without knowing the purpose of this design it is hard to further comment on its usefulness. My "gut feeling" is that you are seriously overthinking it ... One immediate thought is why not parametrize `filterValues` with `E` instead of the entire class:

```
class Parent<V> {
     public <E extends Parent<V>> List<V> filterValues(List<E> entities) {
         ....
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`public class Parent<E extends Parent, V>` bounds `E` with `Parent` which is a raw type. When you access any method or field of `entity`, then, because it has type `E` which is bounded by an erased type, you get the erased type for `Parent`; in particular `V` is `Object`. Hence the error.

Comment: I see, so this is due to type erasure.  How do I ensure that the values in the returned list are of the same type that the entities in the parameter contain?